# Enable logs for Paho MQTT client on AWS Cloudwatch for a Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have written a lambda using **AWS MQTT client to publish to AWS IoT Broker**.
*The AWS MQTT client in its underline uses PAHO MQTT Client*.
Whenever my Lambda is invoked, it publishes the message to the AWS IoT Broker which for now triggers an IoT Rule.
 However, when the duration between the two successive messages invoking the lambda happens to be more than 30 seconds, the client connection is lost. Though a retry logic reestablishes the connection, a few milliseconds are lost.[image]

My initial thought process was that may be the IoT Broker is disconnecting the client due to inactivity. So I wrote a simple program running from my local that connects the IoT Broker.
[image]

I opened the log levels for the class **org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientState** to trace level using **logback.xml**. As it can be seen that the underlying PAHO client continuously sends the PINGREQ packet. The client meets the *keep alive interval* condition and so never gets disconnected.
*My question*:
**Why is the application behaving differently in lambda?**
*My approach :*
In order to know the root cause I, therefore, wanted to open the logs for the same underlying PAHO MQTT Client in CloudWatch.
I tried the following 
[log4j2.xml](https://gist.github.com/rajalive28/78b7970e927aaeadbcf85c6239730c9d)
but could not open the logs by the same class in the cloudwatch. Hence I want to know how do you open the logs of some other library class in your lambda application for Java?

Answer (score 0):

For each lambda execution connect/ publish or subscribe / disconnect should be expected?

Here are more logs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/viewing-logs.html